# Programmatically add AVI file header to video stream

Tags: c#, video, stream, directshow.net, compression

I have a capturing device (analogue to digital converter: AverMedia USB Capture Card).
When I want to record video using DirectShowLib in C#, I only receive frames. I am able to record frames and play the file using RawVideo Player. How can I create a standard video file header like AVI? Second problem occurs when I want to compress the data. When I use compression, I can't read it at all.

Here is my working GraphEdit schema:

[image]

How can I create standard AVI or MPEG file with header and etc?

Answer (score 1):

The playable files have certain structure and captured data is typically written into such file through so called multiplexer filter. For AVI format, the standard filter is [AVI Mux Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It takes video/audio on input and converts into file-compatible stream on the output. If/when this output is connected to File Writer Filter, the latter produces the file with proper headers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/csharp/avi/write_avi.html) you should be able to use this to set up an Avi object, then AddFrame() with your frames to create an avi.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. Because the code just saves incoming frames to a single file. Can I just add video file header to saved frames? I know frames' width, height and fps. Is it possible?

Comment: I downloded DirectShow.NET samples and opened Samples\Capture\DxTuner project. In the project, you can choose a video compressor and create a standard AVI file using DirectShow functions. It records capture device to AVI file.